# FullSerializer & fsSerializer could not be found - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I found some old Unity projects, but when I open them in Unity I get this errors:

1. The type or namespace name `FullSerializer' could not be found.
2. The type or namespace name `fsSerializer' could not be found.

This is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Assertions;
using FullSerializer;

namespace Game.Core
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Miscellaneous file utilities.
    /// </summary>
    public static class FileUtils
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Loads the specified json file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serializer">The FullSerializer serializer to use.</param>
        /// <param name="path">The json file path.</param>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the data to load.</typeparam>
        /// <returns>The loaded json data.</returns>
        public static T LoadJsonFile<T>(fsSerializer serializer, string path) where T : class
        {
            var textAsset = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(path);
            Assert.IsNotNull((textAsset));
            var data = fsJsonParser.Parse(textAsset.text);
            object deserialized = null;
            serializer.TryDeserialize(data, typeof(T), ref deserialized).AssertSuccessWithoutWarnings();
            return deserialized as T;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if the specified path exists and false otherwise.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="path">The path.</param>
        /// <returns>True if the specified path exists; false otherwise.</returns>
        public static bool FileExists(string path)
        {
            var textAsset = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(path);
            return textAsset != null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it by any chance [this library](https://github.com/jacobdufault/fullserializer) which you are missing, and should download and integrate into your project?

Comment: a) this is `c#` not `unityscript`! b) This is not related to Unity at all but rather a missing library / Plug-In / UnityPackage ...

Comment: Yes that fixed it, thank you.